# react-i18next doesn't translate

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

I have tryed to implement `react-i18next` to my react application but it doesn't give a f... that I want it to work
Console doesn't show any error. It just doesn't translate.
Anyone had similar problem and can help me figure out why it doesn't translate?

my `i18n.js` file content:

```js
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import translationPL from './translations/pl/common.json';

const resources = {
    pl: {
        translation: translationPL
    }
};

i18n
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .init({
        resources: resources,
        lng: "pl",
        defaultNS: 'common',

        keySeparator: false,

        interpolation: {
            escapeValue: false
        }
    });


export default i18n;
```

then my `App.js` file

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import './i18n';
import { withTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

class App extends React.Component {
    .
    .
    .
    render() {
        const { t } = this.props;

        return (
            button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => this.endMeeting()}><span className="code-tag">{ t('End meeting') }</span></button>
        );
    }
}

export default withTranslation('common')(App);
```

and lastly `./translations/pl/common.json`

```
{
    "End meeting": "Zakończ posiedzenie"
}
```

---

### update

After enabling debug option it gives me this output:

```
i18next: languageChanged pl
i18next: initialized {debug: true, initImmediate: true, ns: Array(1), defaultNS: "common", fallbackLng: Array(1), …}
i18next::translator: missingKey pl common key_name key_name
i18next::translator: missingKey pl common key_name key_name
```

Comment: try to set the i18next debug option to true

Comment: @adrai debug: languageChanged -> initialization -> missingKey

Comment: Change withTranslation('common') to withTranslation('translation') that’s your ns name

Answer (score 0):

Try to add 'ns' param

```
i18next.init({
  ns: ['common', 'moduleA', 'moduleB'],
  defaultNS: 'moduleA'
}
```

in your case

```
ns: ['common']
```